# Chrome Android resizing some elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, resize, chrome-for-android

I am working on a web app and when I load it up in Chrome for android it shows some very weird text re scaling. Now when I load up the same page in for example DuckDuckGo privacy browser everything is normal. Why does this trigger and how can I prevent it?

[image]images[image]

Answer (score 0):

To all that have the same issue, I found a way to fix it.
I still don't have a clue what caused it but it can be resolved by giving an element a `max-width` and `max-height`.

Something like this:

`* {
    max-width: 999999px;
    max-height: 999999px;
}`